# iphone - Problem loading a table view inside a viewcontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller, nsuserdefaults

I have a TabBarController, which consists of three tabs, one of which is the settings tab. I am trying to sync the settings of the app with NSUserDefaults + settings.bundle and the in app settings that I have in the settings tab. When I change the settings.bundle settings, I use an observer and it sets properties for the in app settings.

The issue I am running into is, if I enter the app, go to the Settings Tab, then exit the app, go to the Settings bundle settings, change a setting, and go back to the settings tab, the setting does not refresh, because table.reloadData is not called then. I tried calling it explicitly from my AppDelegate when the observer is called, but I see no change on the page.

Has anyone encountered a problem like this before? How do I refresh the table / view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use applicationWillEnterForeground: in your app delegate. Maintain a reference to the settings view controller from your tab bar controller and then have your app delegate call a method in your tab bar controller, then settings view controller, from there.

Answer (score 0):

In your settings view controller's `viewDidAppear` method, call `[self.tableView reloadData]`. This will reload the data in the table view every time your settings screen appears.

Comment: viewDidAppear is not called in this case, since I exit the app and application just moves to the foreground when I reenter

Comment: Correct, so you should use applicationWillEnterForeground: in your app delegate. Maintain a reference to the settings view controller from your tab bar controller and then have your app delegate call a method in your tab bar controller, then settings view controller, from there.

Comment: @Alexander Thanks, That worked! Do you want to make your comment into an answer? I would accept it then.